# odb/pgsql/version.hxx no such file or directory

Tags: c++, odbc, odb

I'm trying to learn how to use C++ and ODB following this tutorial:

```
http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/manual.xhtml#2
```

I've created a Person.hxx file where there is the declaration of class Person as persistent, then I've got thre files Person-odb: .cxx, .hxx, .ixx

Now I should compile Person-odb.cxx with

```
g++ -I/usr/lib/odb/i686-linux-gnu/include Person-odb.cxx
```

but it end with:

```
fatal error: odb/pgsql/version.hxx: No such file or directory. compilation terminated.
```

I see that there is a file version.hxx but there's no odb/pgsql directory...
what's wrong?

this is Person.hxx where I have defined the persistent class Person:

```
#ifndef PERSON_HXX
#define PERSON_HXX

#include <string>
#include <odb/core.hxx>

using namespace std;


#pragma db object
class Person {

 private:

  Person() {
  }

  friend class odb::access;


    #pragma db id auto
    unsigned long id_;

  std::string email_;
  std::string first_;
  std::string last_;
  unsigned short age_;

public:

  Person(const std::string& first, const std::string& last,
        unsigned short age);

  /* getters */
  const std::string& first() const;
  const std::string& last() const;
  unsigned short age() const;
  const std::string& email() const;

  /* setters */
  void setAge(unsigned short);
  void setFirst(const std::string&);
  void setLast(const std::string&);
  void setEmail(const std::string&);

};

#endif
```

then I must compile Person.hxx with odb compiler:

```
odb -d mysql --generate-query --generate-schema Person.hxx
```

and I get 4 files Person.odb.hxx, .cxx, .sql, .ixx
this is driver.cxx where I have the main program which persists objects:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include <odb/database.hxx>
#include <odb/transaction.hxx>

#include <odb/mysql/database.hxx>

#include "Person.hxx"
#include "Person-odb.hxx"

using namespace std;
using namespace odb;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

try {
    auto_ptr<database> db (new odb::mysql::database (argc, argv));

    unsigned long marcoID, loryID, lucaID;

    /*Create some persistent Person objects */

    Person marco ("Marco", "Di Nicola", 26);
    Person luca ("Luca", "La Sala", 22);
    Person lory ("Lorenzo", "Vinci", 24);

    transaction t (db->begin());

    marcoID = db->persist(marco);
    lucaID = db->persist(luca);
    loryID = db->persist(lory);

    t.commit();

} catch (const odb::exception& e) {
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
}
```

and this is the file Person-odb.hxx

```
// This file was generated by ODB, object-relational mapping (ORM)
// compiler for C++.
//

#ifndef PERSON_ODB_HXX
#define PERSON_ODB_HXX

#include <odb/version.hxx>

#if (ODB_VERSION != 20200UL)
#error ODB runtime version mismatch
#endif

#include <odb/pre.hxx>

#include "Person.hxx"

#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

#include <odb/core.hxx>
#include <odb/traits.hxx>
#include <odb/callback.hxx>
#include <odb/wrapper-traits.hxx>
#include <odb/pointer-traits.hxx>
#include <odb/container-traits.hxx>
#include <odb/no-op-cache-traits.hxx>
#include <odb/result.hxx>
#include <odb/simple-object-result.hxx>

#include <odb/details/unused.hxx>
#include <odb/details/shared-ptr.hxx>

namespace odb
{
// Person

template <>
struct class_traits< ::Person >
{
  static const class_kind kind = class_object;
};

template <>
class access::object_traits< ::Person >
{


 ...

 #include "Person-odb.ixx"

 #include <odb/post.hxx>

 #endif // PERSON_ODB_HXX
```

everything seems to work fine when I perform:

```
c++ -c Person-odb.cxx
c++ -c driver.cxx
```

but in the end when I have to link all together with:

```
c++ -o driver driver.o Person-odb.o -lodb-mysql -lodb
```

I get:

"undefined reference to `Person::Person(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned short)'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What seems to be your problem is that you didn't install ODB.  The [Installing ODB](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/install-unix.xhtml) page should get you up and running.

You see a version.hxx file, but that's an input file for the ODB compilation process, not for including in your programs.

If you did install it, find out where on your system and add that folder to your compiler include path.  Your compilation command then becomes

```
g++ -I/usr/lib/odb/i686-linux-gnu/include -I/path/to/odb/install/include Person-odb.cxx
```

Following your edits, I think the issue is that you're not linking to the `Person` object file, only the Person-odb one.

Compile `Person.cxx` with

`g++ -c Person.cxx`

and change your linking command to

`g++ -o driver driver.o Person.o Person-odb.o -lodb-mysql -lodb`

and the error should be fixed.

Please note that I don't know ODB.  I'm trying to figure this out from a pure C++ perspective.

Comment: Oh thanks, it worked at last. the problem is that tutorial is not clear enough but it's the only one I've found. Can I ask another thing? I declared the the class Person persisten in file Person.hxx...then odb compiled it generating 4 files Person-odb.hxx, .cxx, .ixx and .sql...well, in the main program I've read I'm supposed to include Person.hxx and Person-odb.hxx but the two can't work together...it says that there's a ridefinition of class Person...what's that?

Comment: Edit your question to add the code from both those files and I might be able to help you out :)

Comment: where? Sorry, I'm very tired afteer hours working on this...can you tell me what you edited? :S